# Subir un excel a visual studio y pasarlo a sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, .net

Tengo un proyecto al cual necesito realizar una carga de archivos. Debo subir un archivo excel, seleccionar el archivo desde el computador y éste pasarlo a una base de datos sql server. He probado con herramientas como sql server data tools, pero al parecer me permite solo subir un archivo especifico.

Comment: Necesitas directo desde tu computador? o Subirlo mediante una app web, parsearlo y luego desde alli a la DB SQL? Pregunto esto porque has etiquetado con [asp.net] tu pregunta.

Comment: Hay una librería que permite trabajar con excel desde C#
EPP Plus [Aquí de dejo un ejemplo de como leer un excel](https://codealoc.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/reading-an-excel-xlsx-file-from-c/) Espero que te sea útil en algo

Answer (score 0):

Si dices [SQL Server Data Tools SSDT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) es un conjunto de herramientas para trabajar en proyectos de base de datos desde Visual Studio por ejemplo.  Pero es para desarrollo, deploy. No para trabajar en aplicaciones.

Si quieres tener en tu app web de ASP.NET soporte para leer hojas de calculo de Excel entonces tendrias que utilizar los componentes de

- [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/) >
  https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/

Que son librerias que nos ayudaran a manipular nuestros documentos ofimaticos. Por ejemplo extraer o editar las hojas de calculo. Por ejemplo para parsear excel...

- [How to: Parse and read a large spreadsheet document (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx)

Y luego que ya tiene los datos parseados en un array u objeto de negocio de tu app, entonces solo queda llevarlos a DB a traves de tu capa de datos o servicios. Pero esto ya es otro tema. Aqui lo unico que te recomiendo que si es un volumen grande de datos la mejor opcion es realizar en Batch al SQL

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Open XML PowerTools](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools)
- [How to: Parse and read a large spreadsheet document (Open XML SDK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg575571.aspx)

Espero que te pueda servir de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, yo tengo una web en ASP.NET con una gran mescolanza de lenguajes, pero dentro de ellos descargué e implementé el plugin [DropzoneJS](https://www.dropzonejs.com/) unido directamente a un archivo ASHX (Handler). La característica principal de este plugin es que su código es muy sencillo de implementar y entender y el handler me permite tener contacto inmediato con el archivo, en pocas palabras creo una ruta y el resto lo almaceno en mi base de datos mediante librerias de manejo de archivos, o sea, no solo es para un archivo excel, sino para todo tipo que quieras almacenar como "Blob".

Mi ejemplo eso si, es válido para bases de datos en PlSql, pero la interpretación debería ser la misma, solo debe cambiar el lenguaje.

```js
 //Configurar Dropzone
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div#myDrop").dropzone({
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/hnFileUpDropzone.ashx" ) %>',
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                maxFilesize: 10,
                maxFiles: 3,
                dictRemoveFile : "Borrar",
                dictDefaultMessage: "Arrastra archivos o haz click acá",
                dictCancelUpload: "Cancelar carga",
                dictUploadCanceled: "Carga cancelada",
                dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "¿Esta seguro que desea cancelar la carga del archivo?",
                dictInvalidFileType: "No puedes subir archivos de este tipo" , 
                acceptedFiles: ".doc,.docx,.mdb,.gdb,.zip,.rar",
                init: function(){
                    this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
                        formData.append("nAccion", nAccion);
                        formData.append("idUsuario", idUsuario);
                        $('#mainZone').html("<img id='barZone' src='img/loader.gif'  height='50' width='50'  />").show();
                    })
                },
                success: function(file, response){
                    var imgName=response;
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                    $('#barZone').hide();
                },
                error: function(file, message){
                    $(file.previewElement).addClass("dz-error").find('.dz-error-message').text("Error encontrado: " + message);
                }
            });
        
        
        });
```

```css
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.IO

Public Class hnFileUpDropzone
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler
    Public fileName As String
    Public fileNameExt As String
    Public cn As New conexion
    Public cnArchivos As HttpContext
    Dim idAccion As String
    Dim idUsuario As String

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest

        Try
            cn.Conectar()
            cnArchivos = context
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
            Dim dirFullPath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")
            Dim files As String()
            Dim numfiles As Integer
            files = Directory.GetFiles(dirFullPath)
            numfiles = files.Length + 1
            idAccion = context.Request.Params("nAccion")
            idUsuario = context.Request.Params("idUsuario")
            Using con As New conexion
                con.Conectar()
                Dim str_image As String = ""
                For Each s As String In context.Request.Files

                    Dim txtSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM observaciones.adjuntos WHERE id=0"
                    Dim da As New Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(txtSQL, con.conexion)
                    Dim tabla As DataTable = cn.DataTable(txtSQL)
                    Dim cb As Npgsql.NpgsqlCommandBuilder = New Npgsql.NpgsqlCommandBuilder(da)
                    Dim fs As FileStream
                    Dim rw As DataRow
                    Dim ruta As String
                    Dim comp As Boolean = False
                    Dim largo As Long = 0


                    Dim file As HttpPostedFile = context.Request.Files(s)
                    fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName)
                    fileNameExt = file.FileName
                    Dim fileExtension As String = file.ContentType
                    ruta = dirFullPath + fileNameExt

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) Then
                            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName)
                            str_image = fileName
                            file.SaveAs(ruta)

                            fs = New FileStream(ruta, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                            Dim dataArchivo(fs.Length - 1) As Byte
                            fs.Read(dataArchivo, 0, fs.Length)
                            fs.Close()
                            Dim md5 As String = GeneraCodigoMD5(dataArchivo)
                            largo = dataArchivo.Length
                            If ruta.Substring(ruta.LastIndexOf(".")).ToLower = ".mdb" Then
                                dataArchivo = Comprime(dataArchivo)
                                comp = True
                            End If

                            Dim adjunto_ = New ClaseAdjunto()
                            adjunto_.id_ = 1
                            adjunto_.nombre_ = fileName
                            adjunto_.rutaCompleta_ = dirFullPath
                            adjunto_.comprimido = False
                            adjunto_.md5_ = ""
                            adjunto_.nbytes_ = context.Request.Files(s).ContentLength

                            rw = tabla.NewRow()
                            rw("id") = 1   
                            rw("id_accion") = idAccion
                            rw("ruta") = ruta
                            rw("archivo") = dataArchivo
                            rw("nombre") = fileName
                            rw("md5") = md5
                            rw("nbytes") = largo
                            rw("comprimido") = If(comp, "s", "n")


                            tabla.Rows.Add(rw)
                            da.Update(tabla)
                            correoArchivo(fileName, largo, idAccion)
                            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(ruta)
                            context.Response.Write(str_image)

                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error de archivo")
        End Try
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.5.1/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalCargaArchivo" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="H1">
                        Cargar archivos a observación</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="dropzone"  action="/" >
                        <div id="myDrop" class="dropzone">
                            <div class="dz-message">Arrastra archivos acá</div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="mainZone"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="reload()">Listo</button>
                <div id="main2"></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

El CSS tiene el Handler para ejemplo.

Espero haberte ayudado!